# Disable Menu Button Bringing Up Status Bar On Samsung Phones

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I am running an app in full screen immersive mode.

On Samsung phones there is a menu button on the device that, when clicked, forces open the status bar at the top. This slides my entire view down and doesn't go away.

How can I prevent the menu click event from displaying the status bar?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, put this in the activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
{
    return false;
}
```